# What design pattern should I use?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have to create project to document conversion.
Base on parameters and specific buissnes type I have to get document from database and convert it to preper typy. It can by a lot of conversion types, for example:  binary document to xmlDocument to transformed xml by xsl or binary document to pdf. For each conversion I use external libraries.
What design pattern should I use? Maybe, factory method foreach specific buissnes type and adapters inside it?

This is only simple sample:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Encoding { get; set; }
    public string CompressionType { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

   public  class DocumentContext
{ 
    public string TransformationParameters { get; set; }

    public string BaseParameters { get; set; }
}

  public interface IDocumentReceiveService<in Params, out Item>
{
    Item GetDocument(Params parameters);
}

public class DocumentReceiveService : 
    IDocumentReceiveService<DocumentContext, DocumentBin>
{
    public DocumentBin GetDocument(DocumentContext parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and DocumentFactory abstraction:

```
public interface IDocumentFactory<in Params, out Item>
{
    Item Create(Params parameters);
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
public class DocumentFactoryXml : IDocumentFactory<DocumentContext, 
    Document>
{
    private readonly IDocumentReceiveService<DocumentContext, DocumentBin> 
        _documentreceiver;

    private readonly DocumentBinToDocumentXmlAdapter _adapter;

    public DocumentFactoryXml(
        IDocumentReceiveService<DocumentContext, DocumentBin> documentreceiver, 
        DocumentBinToDocumentXmlAdapter adapter)
    {
        _documentreceiver = documentreceiver;
        _adapter = adapter;
    }
    public Document Create(DocumentContext parameters)
    {
        var documentBin = _documentreceiver.GetDocument(parameters);

        return _adapter.Adaptee(documentBin);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class DocumentFactoryBin : IDocumentFactory<DocumentContext, 
    Document>
{
    private readonly IDocumentReceiveService<DocumentContext, DocumentBin> 
        _documentreceiver;

    public DocumentFactoryBin(
        IDocumentReceiveService<DocumentContext, DocumentBin> 
            documentreceiver)
    {
        _documentreceiver = documentreceiver;
    }
    public Document Create(DocumentContext parameters)
    {
        return _documentreceiver.GetDocument(parameters);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class DocumentBin: Document
{
}    

public class DocumentXml : Document
{
}

public class DocumentBinToDocumentXmlAdapter
{
    public DocumentXml Adaptee(DocumentBin documentBin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, it is possible to apply `Factory method` here. But it is incorrect way to apply pattern with goal that some pattern should be applied in project. Why? Because it would bring extra layer of abstraction and a little more complexity. If you avoid to add additional complexity, then your code will be simpler. Simple code is almost always the best choice.